# Rate of convergence for a sequence (Preferably without Taylor series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Knowing that the sequence $(a_{n})$ with:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+\frac{3}{a_{n}})$$
converges to $\sqrt{3}$, find it's rate of convergence.

After doing some searching, I found this formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Q-convergence_definitions):

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}-L|}{|a_{n}-L|} = μ$$
And I think that our L is $\sqrt{3}$.
Do I need to find the value of $a_{n}$ to find the rate of convergence (μ)? And how do I find $a_{n}$ ?

**UPDATE:** I can simply use the formula above but I need to make my limit approach to $\sqrt{3}$ because we have $a_{n} \to \sqrt{3}$:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \sqrt{3}} \frac{|\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{3}{x})-\sqrt{3}|}{|x-\sqrt{3}|}$$

But my problem is that this limit is resulting in a indeterminate form because of $\frac{0}{0}$

How can I solve this limit without expanding series?

**UPDATE 2 - ANSWER:**
Using @[user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/505767/user)'s approach we can write our limit as:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \sqrt{3}} \frac{\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{3}{x})-\sqrt{3}}{x-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{x^2-2\sqrt 3x+3}{2x(x-\sqrt{3})}=\frac{(x-\sqrt{3})^2}{2x(x-\sqrt{3})}=\frac{x-\sqrt{3}}{2x}\to 0$$

and then the sequence converges Q-superlinearly to $\sqrt 3$. Look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Q-convergence_definitions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-\sqrt 3}{a_{n+1}+\sqrt 3}=\frac{a_n^2-2\sqrt 3a_n+3}{a_n^2+2\sqrt 3a_n+3}=\left(\frac{a_{n}-\sqrt 3}{a_{n}+\sqrt 3}\right)^2$$

therefore by induction with $a_0=a>0$ we have that

$$\frac{a_{n}-\sqrt 3}{a_{n}+\sqrt 3}=\left(\frac{a-\sqrt 3}{a+\sqrt 3}\right)^{2^{n}}$$

and therefore

$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt 3\left(1+\left(\frac{a-\sqrt 3}{a+\sqrt 3}\right)^{2^{n}}\right)}{1-\left(\frac{a-\sqrt 3}{a+\sqrt 3}\right)^{2^{n}}}$$

Refer to the related

- [Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2265615/505767)

---

By a limit approach we have

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{3}{x})-\sqrt{3}}{x-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{x^2-2\sqrt 3x+3}{2x(x-\sqrt{3})}=\frac{(x-\sqrt{3})^2}{2x(x-\sqrt{3})}=\frac{x-\sqrt{3}}{2x}\to 0$$

and then the sequance converges Q-superlinearly to $\sqrt 3$.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: @CELESTE The limit is zero, you can use l'Hopital to evaluate it or factotization.

Comment: Can you show me how? I am not really sure on how to use L'Hospital on this one, also I don't wanna use methods such as series expansion. Getting zero is the right answer so since our limit is zero the sequence is said to converge Q-superlinearly to $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @CELESTE I've added also this derivation. I thought you were interested to the rate of convergence which indeed is a harder problem.

Comment: Thank you for your approach, my problem is solved ! I shall update my question with the answer soon.

Comment: @CELESTE That's nice. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

@ClaudeLeibovici notes this iteration is by the Newton-Raphson method; so, under mild conditions (which apply here), the convergence is quadratic (i.e. the [order of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Q-convergence_definitions) is $2$) so $\mu=0$. @user's work makes this easy to check. With $x:=\tfrac{a-\sqrt{3}}{a+\sqrt{3}}$ we have$$a_n-\sqrt{3}=2\sqrt{3}x^{2^n}\underbrace{\frac{1}{1-x^{2^n}}}_{\sim1}\implies\frac{a_{n+1}-\sqrt{3}}{(a_n-\sqrt{3})^2}\sim\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}},$$where we've used the convergence requirement $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2^n}=0$.

To address the update, note that$$\begin{align}\lim{y\to\sqrt{3}}\frac{(y+3/y)/2-\sqrt{3}}{y-\sqrt{3}}&=\lim{z\to0}\frac{z-\sqrt{3}+3/(z+\sqrt{3})}{2z}\\&=\lim{z\to0}\frac{z}{2(z+\sqrt{3})}\\&=0.\end{align}$$Again, we can prove something stronger with a squared denominator:$$\lim{z\to0}\frac{z-\sqrt{3}+3/(z+\sqrt{3})}{2z^2}=\lim{z\to0}\frac{1}{2(z+\sqrt{3})}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}},$$as in the above calculations.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: @CELESTE I've edited my answer to address your follow-up question. (The modulus signs in your limit are a trivial addition.)

Comment: Thank you for your approach, my problem is solved ! I shall update my question with the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} \left(a_n+\frac{3}{a_n}\right)=a_{n}-\frac{a_n^2-3}{2 a_n}$$

This looks like Newton iteration for the root of $x^2-3=0$

Comment: Check my update.